# htmlagilitypack gzip encryption exception

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm having the exception throw gzip is not support.  This is all i'm using the load the page, any idea on how to allow gzip?

```
        HtmlWeb hwObject = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmldocObject = hwObject.Load(siteURL);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can download the page yourself, i.e. using a class derived from `WebClient` (or manually making a `WebRequest` and setting `AutomaticDecompression` )

```
public class GZipWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        return request;
    }
}
```

Given this you can do:

```
string html;
using(var wc = new GZipWebClient())
  html = wc.DownloadString(siteUrl);

var htmldocObject = new HtmlDocument();
htmldocObject.LoadHtml(html);
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, i was looking for a way to handle this exception though

Comment: last I checked you can either modify the HtmlAgilityPack source code, i.e. see here: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/22790 or need to download the content yourself

Comment: @Mike - Grab the source from [the repository](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets), make your changes, and compile it yourself.