# I have use HtmlAgilityPack Parse a value on website but my programming not run

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2013, html-agility-pack

**I have written a programming get value on website mp3.zing.vn but HtmlAgilityPack error. 
My code is below:**

```
string trave = "";          
String url = "http://mp3.zing.vn/bang-xep-hang/bai-hat-Viet-Nam/IWZ9Z08I.html";
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
HtmlWeb a = new HtmlWeb();
doc = a.Load(url);
HtmlNodeCollection t =doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class=\"txtprimary\"]");
foreach (var i in t){ trave += i.InnerText; }
```

Error Image
http://postimg.org/image/5uuqby5ov/

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: Should we deduce exact error you're getting? Or maybe you will disclosure that secret?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: @Jetly_93: What's the message on the exception?  What's the stack trace?  We can't see your computer screen, you have to actually provide us with information about the error.

Comment: @David My Screen
http://postimg.org/image/5uuqby5ov/

Comment: @Jetly_93 See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936089/htmlagilitypack-gzip-encryption-exception

Comment: The *very first* result when searching the error message one Google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936089/htmlagilitypack-gzip-encryption-exception

Comment: @Jetly_93 Are you sure your document source contains `txtprimary` class?

Comment: Thanks! download all html of website before get value by HtmlAgilityPack

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems in your code.

1- In downloading the gzipped content

2- selecting the correct anchors.

```
String url = "http://mp3.zing.vn/bang-xep-hang/bai-hat-Viet-Nam/IWZ9Z08I.html";
var data = new WebClient().DownloadData(url);
var html =  new StreamReader(new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(data), CompressionMode.Decompress)).ReadToEnd();

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var t = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='txt-primary']")
        .Select(a => a.InnerText)
        .ToList();
```

OUTPUT:

> [ "Chưa Bao Giờ", "Ấn Nút Nhớ…Thả Giấc Mơ", "Vâng Anh Đi Đi", "2AM", "Làm Vợ Anh Nhé", "Buông", "Say You Do", "Alone", "Đẹp Trai Thì Mới Có Nhiều Đứa Yêu", "Thế Giới Ảo Tình Yêu Thật", "Giá Như", "Đơn Phương", "Mr. Right (Khi Anh Yêu Em)", "Không Phải Dạng Vừa Đâu", "Anh Là Của Em", "Buông", "Khuôn Mặt Đáng Thương", "Người Từng Yêu Anh Rất Sâu Nặng", "Cứ Thế Mong Chờ", "Phố Thị", "Thật Bất Ngờ", "Cám Ơn Vì Tất Cả", "Em Là Của Anh", "Xin Đừng Buông Tay", "Chạy (On My Way)", "Ai Cũng Có Nỗi Buồn", "Mãi Luôn Gần Nhau", "Vẫn Cứ Yêu Em", "Lời Tỏ Tình", "Vợ Yêu", "Con Nợ Mẹ", "Anh Không Sao Đâu", "Con Đường Tôi", "Không Có Em", "My Everything", "Cho Những Điều Đã Qua", "Không Thuộc Về Nhau", "Em Của Quá Khứ", "Độc Ẩm", "Có Lẽ" ]