# Gzip, HTMLAgilitypack

Tags: c#, parsing, gzip, html-agility-pack

i have some problems with Gzip in HTMLAgillityPack
Error - 'gzip' is not a supported encoding name

Code:

```
var url = "http://poe.trade/search/arokazugetohar";
var web = new HtmlWeb();

var htmldoc = web.Load(url);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htmlagilitypack gzip encryption exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936089/htmlagilitypack-gzip-encryption-exception)

Answer (score 6):

You can add gzip encoding using below method.

```
var url = "http://poe.trade/search/arokazugetohar";

HtmlWeb webClient = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.PreRequestHandler handler = delegate (HttpWebRequest request)
{
    request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip, deflate";
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
    request.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
    return true;
 };
 webClient.PreRequest += handler;

 HtmlDocument doc = webClient.Load(url);
```