# Character encoding wrong in HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack to scrape an special web site.
unfortunately it return wrong character like this:
`\u001f�\b\0KMg_\0��}]s\u001cǑ��F�\u007fh3.\u0016�\u0019\u001f�]ݠ�\`

and this :
`\u001f�\b\0�Rg_\0��}]s\u001cǑ��F�\u007fh3.\u0016�\u0019\u001f��\u0560�\`
but other web page return I expected
how can I solve it?

Comment: Rather use AngleSharp.

Comment: show code and url for reproducing the problem

Comment: @derloopkat Actually I'm using this web site: http://tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx in simple example as on HtmlAgilityPack official web site.

Comment: @Alireza Your question is a duplicate of this [Gzip, HTMLAgilitypack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53701388/gzip-htmlagilitypack). I've realised that after checking the response `Content-Encoding: gzip` in Developer Tools. Tested the code in the answer I've mentioned and worked.

Comment: @derloopkat Thanks that resolve my problem.